# How to text index in mongodb using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to create a text index for text search implementation in mongodb using nodejs.

Ex :

```
db.collection("test").ensureIndex(
                       { 
                          name: 'text', 
                          description: 'text' 
                       }, 
                       { 
                          weights: { name: 10, description: 20 }, 
                           name: 'test' 
                      }, function(err, data){

                 // here err is null, and data is "test"

 });
```

After that i am trying to get information of this index with name "test", it is giving me data like

```
 { v: 1,
   key: { _fts: 'text', _ftsx: 1 },
   ns: '53b3e49b31afd3d3354886b7_rajeshdemo.test',
   name: 'test',
   weights: { description: 1, name: 1 },
   default_language: 'english',
   language_override: 'language',
   textIndexVersion: 1 
}
```

It is not taking weight information.

How can i create text search index in mongodb(version 2.6) using nodejs?

Comment: If an index already exists matching the provided key spec ({name:'text',description:'text') then `ensureIndex` will not recreate the index with new options. Have you tried dropping the index and then re-ensuring?

Comment: Yes, i am droping the text index before calling ensureIndex.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

Actually i am using nodejs mongodb driver 1.4.5. After updating the version to 1.4.9, it is working fine.